# Resaltar un color especifico en una imagen

Tags: javascript, css, canvas

Tengo la necesidad de resaltar un color/tono en imagenes para dejar el resto en blanco y negro
como por ejemplo en la siguiente intentando resaltar el azul.
No se hasta que punto se puede hacer esto con css o incluso trabajando con el canvas. He estado consultando en MDN los [mix-blend-mode](https://developer.cdn.mozilla.net/es/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode).

```css
.resaltado {
   mix-blend-mode: normal; 
   filter: grayscale(100%);
 }

.azul {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="azul">
  <img class="resaltado" src="https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/diesel-generator-for-emergency-power-supply-at-the-wall-of-a-medical-picture-id1202591741?b=1&k=6&m=1202591741&s=170667a&w=0&h=aa91rX5JDdVH2plVczpYnWFNMiswXb2N8kL3oueBqxo=" >
</div>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No se me ocurre cómo hacerlo con puro CSS, pero con Javascript en un canvas podrías procesar la imagen, cambiando pixel a pixel el color: si el color predominante de un pixel no es azul, lo cambias a gris (sacando la luminosidad media de cada color):

```js
const canvasB = document.querySelector('#blue');
const canvasR = document.querySelector('#red');
const canvasG = document.querySelector('#green');

function loadImage() {
  return new Promise(success => {
    const img = new Image();
    img.crossOrigin = '';
    img.src = 'https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/diesel-generator-for-emergency-power-supply-at-the-wall-of-a-medical-picture-id1202591741?b=1&k=6&m=1202591741&s=170667a&w=0&h=aa91rX5JDdVH2plVczpYnWFNMiswXb2N8kL3oueBqxo='
    img.onload = () => success(img);
  });
}

loadImage().then(img => {
    applyFilter(canvasB, 'blue', img);
    applyFilter(canvasR, 'red', img);
    applyFilter(canvasG, 'green', img);
});

function isMainColor(color, r, g, b) {
  switch (color) {
    case "blue" : return (b >= r && b >= g);
    case "red"  : return (r >= b && r >= g);
    case "green": return (g >= r && g >= b);
    default: return false;
  }
}

function applyFilter(canvas, color, img) {
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  const imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  
  for (let i = 0; i < imgData.data.length; i += 4) { //RGBA, 4 bytes por pixel
    const red = imgData.data[i];
    const green = imgData.data[i + 1];
    const blue = imgData.data[i + 2];
    // el cuarto valor es el canal alpha, que lo ignoramos
    if (isMainColor(color, red, green, blue)){
      continue;
      // si este pixel es del color que queremos, lo dejamos tal cual
      // y pasamos al siguiente
    }
    // para pasar a gris, calculamos la media de los 3 canales
    let average = Math.floor((red + green + blue) / 3);
    imgData.data[i] = average;
    imgData.data[i + 1] = average;
    imgData.data[i + 2] = average;
  }
  ctx.putImageData(imgData, 0, 0);
}
```

```css
img, canvas {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/diesel-generator-for-emergency-power-supply-at-the-wall-of-a-medical-picture-id1202591741?b=1&k=6&m=1202591741&s=170667a&w=0&h=aa91rX5JDdVH2plVczpYnWFNMiswXb2N8kL3oueBqxo=" />
<canvas id ="blue" width="509" height="339"> </canvas>
<canvas id ="red" width="509" height="339"> </canvas>
<canvas id ="green" width="509" height="339"> </canvas>
```

Comment: Es justo lo que queria, además de que me ha servido para entender mejor el canvas!!!.Gracias